# Why doesn't the Cisco WebDialer API use the lineNumber specified when dialing a call?

Tags: api, telephony, cisco

I am using the Cisco WebDialer API to place calls for users with multiple lines. When calling `makeCallSoap`, the `lineNumber` property of the `UserProfile` argument seems to be ignored. The call is dialed successfully, but the user's default line is always used rather than the line specified in the `UserProfile` argument.

How can I dial a call using a line other than the default with the WebDialer API?